# how to restart socket properly in a multithread c/c++ program

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, socket.io, network-programming

Background: My code structure: I have a master socket on main thread, then each time a new client is coming, the threadpool will be notified and let one pre allocated thread take the task.
Inside this thread, I will pass a slave socket to it, and let it using `accept` call to listen to the client.

Scenario: In my thread pool, thread A is listening to a client right now, now I want to stop all the pre-allocated thread and close all the connection to the client,     the main thread is trying to close the connection using  `close` the connection to the client,  and trying to terminate thread A using `pthread_join`.

```
main() {
     
   // create threadpool
   // logic to create mastersocket

   startServer(masterSock)
    

   IwantToCloseServer() // this function is not directly called in main, but simulated by a terminal signal , like kill -quit pid.
}


int startServer(int msock) {
    int ssock; // slaveSocket 
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr; // the address of the client...
    unsigned int client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr); // ... and its length
    
    
    while (!stopCondition) {
        // Accept connection:
             ssock = ::accept((int)msock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);   //  the return value is a socket
        // I was trying to replace this line of code to poll(), but it's not does the same thing as before  

        
    
        if (ssock < 0) {
             if (errno == EINTR) continue;
             perror("accept");
             running =0;
             return 0;
         // exit(0);
        } else {
           
            // push task to thread pool to deal with logic
            
        }
        
     // main thread continues with the loop...
    }
    
    return 1;
    
}

IwantToCloseServer(slaveSocket) {
     
    // when i want to close() or shutdown() function to close connections, these 2 function always return -1, because the thread is blocked on accept call

    // logic try to terminate all the preallocated threads, the pthread_join function is stuck because the thread is blocked on accept

}
```

Problem: The thread  A is keeping blocking on the `::accept`  function , the `close` and `shutdown` function return -1, they won’t close the connection , and the `pthread_join` is not keep going because thread A is blocked on `accept`.

Things I tried:

1. I have try to change my while loop related accept function, for example, set a flag *stopCondition*,

   ```
   while(!stopConditon) {

               ssock = ::accept((int)msock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len); 

       }
   ```

   However, when the main thread change *stopCondtion*, the thread A is blocked inside the `accept` function.
   It won’t go inside the `while` loop, so this solution won’t affect the `accept` function, it’s not working
2. I have also tried to send a signal to this blocked Thread A, using

   ```
   pthread_cancel or pthread_kill(Thread A, 9)
   ```

   However, if I do this, the whole process gets killed.

3.try to use `poll()` to replace the line, where the `accept` functions at, with a timeout

however, the program doesn't behave like before, the program can't listen to client anymore.

How do I terminate thread A (which is blocked on `accept` function call right now), so that I can clean this pre allocated thread and restart my server ?

btw i can not use library like boost in my current program. And this is under linux system not winsocket

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: @slipz just did

Comment: call `accept` in a loop starting by a `select` with timeout to be able to check stopConditon inside *periodically*. Out of that `while(!stopConditon) {
 if(!stopCondtion) {` is redundant and can be replaced by `while(!stopConditon) {`. It is also strange to see nowhere a call to `listen`

Comment: Please post your _entire_ code in a [single] code block. It should compile cleanly, be downloadable, and runnable. What you posted is still too sparse to determine your problem.

Comment: stopCondition is a shared resource. You should use it in a cond_var instead. If thread A is waiting on ::accept you need to kill the socket from the main thread that knows you want to exit. Again the socket is a shared resource so you need to use a cond_var along with associated mutex. pthread_join() will keep on waiting indefinitely until thread A has been relinquished.

Comment: Dont use pthread_cancel() or pthread_kill(). pthread_join() is the sane way to let the thread retire properly.

Comment: @OS2 *stopCondition is a shared resource. You should use it in a cond_var instead* no, it is just a `int̀` or something like, a thread can read it and an other thread modify it without any problem

Comment: @OS2 *Again the socket is a shared resource so you need to use a cond_var along with associated mutex* no, socket functions are reentrant

Comment: Regardless of it being an int, the stopCondition is still a shared resource. You can still send a close signal via the socket then if it is not a shared resource.

Comment: @OS2 sure *stopCondition* it a shared resource, the problem is not here and I reacted about "You should use it in a cond_var instead" which is absolutely false

Answer (score 1):

to check periodically *stopConditon* in your `while(!stopConditon) {` first call `accept`/`pool` with a timeout to know if there is something new about *msock*, then depending on the result call `accept` etc else do nothing

> I was trying to replace this line of code to poll()
>
> try to use poll() to replace the line, where the accept functions at, with a timeout

you cannot *replace* `accept` by `poll`, you have to call `accept` / `pool` first and of course check the result then may be call `accept`

Out of that

```
while(!stopConditon) {
    if(!stopCondtion) {
```

is redundant and can be replaced by

```
while(!stopConditon) {
```